# How do I get contents of collections with generics?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I  get object from hibernate query. Then i have list of fields, whose getters i must invoke on this object. So after i invoke these getters (not depending on me, so i have no idea what they return), i put these objects in one array Object[]. Now i  am iterating through these objects, some of which are again collections containing other objects.
So i check if objects is collection like this

```
private static boolean isCollection(Object obj){
    Class clazz = obj.getClass();
    return Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz) ||     
     Map.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
}
```

now i need to do somethinhg like:

```
 if(isCollection(object)){
       get subobjects from this collection();
       getDeclaredMethods of this type of object();
       do something with everyObject();
}
```

Appreciate all the help on how to make this generic. Oh and yes, this method is checking for a Map, but in general in my case, map can not be returned, only sets and lists.

Thank you

EDIT: I will add exact code here for reference in case it is not clear

```
Object[] objectRow = parseObject(hibernateObject);
for(Object field: objectRow){
      get subobjects from this collection();
   getDeclaredMethods of this type of object();
   do something with everyObject();
```

}

```
public Object[] parseObject(Object mainObject) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException{
    rowToReturn = new Object[fieldObjects.size()];

    Method[] allMethods = mainObject.getClass().getMethods();
    Method[] getters = findGetters(allMethods);
    cutGetters(getters); // builds map so that we match getters with fields



    for(FieldObject field: fieldObjects){
        if(getterNameMethodMap.containsKey(field.getFinalFieldName())){
            Method methodToInvoke = getterNameMethodMap.get(field.getFinalFieldName());

            Object invokedObject = methodToInvoke.invoke(mainObject, (Object) null);
            rowToReturn[field.getOrder()] = invokedObject; // put what ever it is that we got, into the final array
        }
    }

    return rowToReturn;
}


private void cutGetters(Method[] getters){
    getterNameMethodMap = new HashMap<String, Method>();
    for(Method getter:getters){
        String stringToGet = getter.getName().substring(4,getter.getName().length());
        getterNameMethodMap.put(stringToGet, getter);
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need a collection containing both "non-collection" objects and other collections? It is rarely a good decision to have a collection containing objects from different class hierarchies.

Comment: @stoupa: i am getting an object from hibernate query. On that object I am must invoke some getter methods, and whatever they return i must put in this list....at moment i dont see how its appropriate to separate them, because i never know what i will get, can be anything :/

Comment: @Julia: If I understand it correctly, you are adding results returned from different getter methods (with different return types) to the one collection mentioned above. Is that right?

Comment: @stoupa yes. I get object from hibernate query. then i have list of fields, whose getters i must invoke. so after i invoke these getters(not depending on me, so i have no idea what they return), i put these objects in one list. Then i must do what i explained above that i must do :)

Comment: @Julia: Could you perhaps post the part of your code you are describing?

Comment: @stoupa: i added the code. One correction, as you will see, i was adding these subobjects to Object[] then i loop through array, not a list. but problem is the same. Thank you for efforts

Comment: instead of `Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)` you should just use `obj instanceof Collection`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the code Generics try to prevent. Generics try to take the burden of scattering `if object.type == class` throughout your code from you. Have a look here, this is only an introduction:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Since you have a **collection of collections** of objects, you would do something like this:

```
List<List<? extends Shape>>
```

This is to declare a list of lists and also to be as precise as possible which kind of object those inner lists contain (I chose Shape just as an example, no idea which kind of objects you want to deal with). You can find the explanation for that exact code here:

> http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: i do not have collection of collections, i have collection of objects. Some of those objects are collections ( i wrote like that :)) , some are strings, some are some third objects. So List<List<? extends Shape>> can not be defined over my list.

Comment: This is very unusual. Maybe you can change the method(s) that generate(s) this collection? e.g. instead of having list{list,string,list,string} to this: list{list{},list{string},list{},list{string}}. This is far better if you want to iterate over...

Comment: you can take a look, i edited my original post to explain how i get this initial list of different objects. Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Because Generics are erased at compile-time, by definition they cannot be used to determine the type of an object if you cannot know that type at compile-time. Unfortunately, without changing whatever code is giving you the array of objects that may or may not be Collections, the only way to determine their type is to manually check the returned Objects' types like you are already doing.

Further info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

P.S.: that's not to say there isn't a more efficient way of doing what you're doing. By casting those objects that you have already determined are Collections, you may be able to "do something" without resorting to reflection to get the declared methods. The actual determination, however, cannot be shortcut with Generics.